# Second entrance to Schengen area on a multiple entrance visa

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, multiple-entry

I have a multiple entrance Schengen visa issued by Netherlands. My first flight land in Netherlands too. However I'm planning to leave Schengen area to Turkey and return to Schengen via Italy while my visa is valid.
Is this allowed? Or do I need to enter through Netherlands for the subsequent entrances too?

Comment: While your **boss** is valid???

Comment: Is that the itinerary you stated when you applied for your Schengen visa? How long are you planning to spend in the Netherlands before going to Turkey?

Comment: @AugustineofHippo look at a keyboard with QWERTZ or QWERTY layout and imagine a little deviation of their fingers while typing and maybe a little auto-correct, and you might easily get boss instead of visa (3 letters each 1 key off).

Comment: I corrected both misspellings of "visa."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your plan is fine in principle.

For a multiple entries visa, it is not required to always enter in the country that issued the visa (issuing country).

You should make sure that you follow the itinerary or itineraries you submitted when obtaining the visa. If your plans changed, you should be prepared to justify a different itinerary when asked about it, and if possible it would be a good idea to notify the issuing authority about it, if it materially changes your application (e.g. if you're now going to a different country, this may be seen as deceptive, as you should have applied to that country instead).

Comment: "It's a guideline that you should enter that country on your first visit": there is no such guideline.  In fact, there are many itineraries where it is impossible to do so.

Comment: @phoog I rephrased that and the next paragraph